# Setup jenkins with php project

Tags: php, jenkins

I am using jenkins with .net projects and it is working good. but now I need to deploy my php project using jenkins on my windows machine. I saw many tutorials but did not understood.

Could you please help me out to deploy php project using jenkins?

Working enviroment. I have one windows server where I am running my jenkins server. and my php project code is on my local system.

Answer (score 0):

you can use appropriate deployment plugin for Jenkins, [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin) supports few application servers.

Comment: Actually I don't know php, I just want to deploy developed project, could you please tell me which type of command I need to write in build section of jenkins?

Comment: I simply want to deploy my php project using jenkins, I dont want to perform any kind of code/test analysis. what will be steps to be performed to deploy php project using jenkins. please help me out with details explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can follow the below steps:

1. checkout the code
2. create artifact like .zip in PHP
3. use post build action and archive artifact plugin
4. in another job of deployment use plugin copy artifact from another job as
   [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1ssf.jpg)